# growth rate of the instability of a laminar flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, stability

I was just studying something about The Plateau-Rayleigh Instability that I saw something called Growth rate of the instability.

My question is the exact physical definition of growth rate of instability in this field (Plateau-Rayleigh Instability) if you put a picture, I'll be more appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about linear stability analysis?

Comment: Almost nothing. If I need to know, I'll study wikipedia about it. Do I need to know that?

Comment: I think the growth rate will follow logically from the linear stability analysis. I do not have the time for a detailed answer, but I guess an instability will grow exponentially $\exp(rt)$, then $r$ is your growth rate. I hope this already helps a bit. Are you studying this for a course or just out of interest?

Comment: I'm just 16 years old

Comment: @David2000 - I applaud your enthusiasm to read up on this subject but I must warn you that hydrodynamic instability is a difficult subject for a highschool student. It requires atleast a college level understanding of physics and calculus. But don't let that deter you from trying to understand it.

Comment: No problem. I've studied so many things on mechanic and fluids. But I'll try. Thanks sir

Comment: And I have the college level understanding of calculus.

Answer (score 2):

The growth rate of the instability is the characteristic rate $r$ at which a pertubation grows in an unstable dynamic system.

A good reference on this type of instabilities is:

*Capillarity and Wetting Phenomena: Drops, Bubbles, Pearls, Waves*
by *Pierre-Gilles de Gennes, Francoise Brochard-Wyart, David Quere*
ISBN 0-387-00592-7

On page 120, it describes a Plateau-Rayleigh instability as occurs on a fibre with an initially uniform film of liquid on its surface. What follows is a summary of that analysis:

[image]

In the picture, $e$ is a film thickness at some time  given by:
$$ e = e_0 + \delta\left(t\right)\cos\left(\kappa x\right)$$
where $e_0$ is the initial film thickness, $\kappa=2\pi/\lambda$ is the wavenumber and $\delta$ is a time-dependent pertubation. The evolution of the pertubation is found to be:
$$\frac{d\delta}{dt} = \frac{\gamma e_0^3}{3\eta b^2}\kappa^2\left[1-\left(\kappa b\right)^2\right]\delta = r\delta$$

where $\gamma$, $\eta$ and $b$ are surface tension, viscosity, and length scale of the surface (see picture) respectively.

For the pertubation to grow (i.e. $d_t\delta>0$), we require that $\kappa b<1$ which is the case when the initial film thickness is much smaller than the characteristic length scale of the surface ($\kappa b$ is a ratio of length scales). As mentioned by Bernhard in the comments, the pertubation then grows as $\exp\left(rt\right)$ with a characteristic rate for a particular wavelength:
$$r = \frac{\gamma e_0^3}{3\eta b^2}\kappa^2\left[1-\left(\kappa b\right)^2\right]$$

The smallest wavelength in the system is $\lambda=2\pi\sqrt{2}b$, which yields the smallest (characteristic) time scale:
$$r \approx \frac{1}{12}\frac{\gamma e_{0}^{3}}{\eta b^{4}}$$

Which shows that the length scale of the system and the initial thickness have a large impact on the growth rate.

Comment: Sorry but just one thing. what do you exactly mean by  characteristic length scale of the surface? can u send a picture and show it? I've studied about it but never face to this " characteristic length scale of the surface "

Comment: Nice answer, but three remarks. 1. A timescale is not a rate. The growth rate would be $1/\tau$. 2. It would be useful to relate a thin film to the Rayleigh-Plateau instability (they are very similar indeed). 3. Your use of $q$ and $b$ need a bit more introduction, I don't understand right away what you mean.

Comment: I also thought that is should be related to Rayleigh-Plateau instability. And I was studying an article about that, which this question came to my mind

Comment: @David2000 - I have added a picture and clarified some of the terms as suggested. I just realized considering your previous question on this subject you were probably interested in the Rayleigh-Plateau rather than the Plateau-Rayleigh instability, they are similar. For the Rayleigh-Plateau instability check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_thread_breakup) out and the references cited there.

Comment: Can you send me the Book ( Capillarity and Wetting Phenomena: Drops, Bubbles, Pearls, Waves ) ?

Comment: @David2000 - Sorry that is most likely against the rules of SE. There is a preview [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=KifrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=Capillarity+and+Wetting+Phenomena:+Drops,+Bubbles,+Pearls+plateau+rayleigh&source=bl&ots=W4OwzvShnL&sig=2VzZZRLeUCEytz6pqZLjcp8dAVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwA2oVChMIzaeewrD0xwIVA1wUCh1UZw-L#v=onepage&q=plateau-rayleigh&f=false) and maybe google is your friend.